# What is the scope of the pipeline tasks (for example command line/delete files) running on an hosted agent?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When the pipeline runs, it first downloads the repo files (Get Sources). Then I can unit test/build the project using a command line task if required. This is followed by deleting the files using the 'Delete Files' task. Any environment variables are scoped to this pipeline only and get cleared when pipeline execution completes. Any files created remain forever (unless deleted using 'Delete Files' or command line task).

What is the scope of the command line and delete files pipeline tasks running on an hosted agent? Can it access the entire hard disk of the agent (like all drives/files)? Is it build folder scoped or agent folder scoped or entire agent hard disk scoped?

Comment: Microsoft hosted agent or Self-hosted agent?

Comment: Would be good to know both

Comment: In fact I think it's the same :) see my answer.

Comment: @variable Not get your latest information, is Shayki's answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I cannot access d:\

Comment: @variable Sorry for the late response.I tested with a host agent, it is possible to access D: \. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4BJJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The scope is to the entire hard disk.

You can use Command Line or any other tasks and perform operations in your system, not only in the build agent folder.